# How to retrive data from drop-downlist to textbox in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I had to retrieve data from the database (MySQL) to drop-down list in PHP. Now, I wanna retrieve data from drop-down list into the textbox.

This is my code.

```
<form method="POST">
    <select name="searchtitle" id="drp_dwn">
      <?php
        $records = $conn->query("SELECT titles from products");
        if ($records->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row = $records->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<option value=\"\"> ".$row['titles']."</option>";
            $titles1 = $row['titles'];
          }
        }
      ?>  
    </select>     
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Show">
    <input type="text" id="textArea" class="product-new-textbox" name="searchtitle" value='<?php echo $row['titles']; ?>' />
</form>
```

I attach with images.
[image: my images]

I hope you can support me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, add an empty `action` attribute to the `form` and populate the new `input` with the title selected when the form has been submitted. Also change the last inputs name as `searchtitle` is already being used by the `select` and add a `selected` attribute to the `option` element:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="searchtitle" id="drp_dwn">
        <?php
        $records = $conn->query("SELECT titles from products");
        if ($records->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row = $records->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $selected = '';
                if ($row['titles'] === $_POST['searchtitle'])
                {
                    $selected = 'selected';
                }
                echo "<option " . $selected . " value=\"" . $row['titles'] . "\"> " . $row['titles'] . "</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>  
    </select>     
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Show">
    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST))
    {
    ?>
        <input type="text" id="textArea" class="product-new-textbox" name="searchtitle1" value="<?php echo $_POST['searchtitle']; ?>" />
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks bro. And have a small problem. When I select another titles (example: Test1) , then in Textbox is displayed Test1, but in Drop downlist is not Test1 (It back to "Test title" of first row of Dropdown list). 
I wanna when I selected "Test1" and click to button "Show" then Dropdownlist and Textbox is same content. Sorry my english.

Comment: That should do the job : )

Comment: Wow. You are perfect. Thank bro so much.

Comment: Yeah. I have a some problem. Can I question to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186911/discussion-between-donald-sys-and-matt-fryer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form method="POST">
        <select name="searchtitle" id="drp_dwn">
          <?php
            $records = $conn->query("SELECT titles from products");
            if ($records->num_rows > 0) {
              while ($row = $records->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option value=\"\"> ".$row['titles']."</option>";
                $titles1 = $row['titles'];
              }
            }
          ?>  
        </select>     
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Show">
        <input type="text" id="textArea" class="product-new-textbox" name="searchtitle" value='<?php echo $row['titles']; ?>' />
    </form>
```

simple JS code

```
<script>
$(document).on("click","#submit",function(){
var x = $("#drp_dwn").val();
$("#textArea").val(x);
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Do you want to show the dropdown value in the text box? This code will show the dropdown value in the text box on changing the dropdown value and on click the show button.
I have created a showText() function which you can call anywhere either on click the show button or on change the dropdown. You can change the dropdown option values by using your php while loop. Here is the example code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
    <select name="searchtitle" id="drp_dwn" onchange="showText()">
      <option value="one" >One</option>
      <option value="Two" >Two</option>
      <option value="Three" >Three</option>
    </select>     
    <input type="button" onclick="showText()" class="button" value="Show">
    <input type="text" id="textArea" class="product-new-textbox" name="searchtitle" value='' />
</form>
<script>
    function showText()
  {
    $("#textArea").val($("#drp_dwn").val()); 
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
<form method="POST"  action="" >
    <select name="searchtitle" id="drp_dwn">
      <option value="one" >One</option>
      <option value="Two" >Two</option>
      <option value="Three" >Three</option>
    </select>     
    <input type="submit" onclick="showText()" class="button" value="Show">
    <input type="text" id="textArea" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['searchtitle'])){ echo $_POST['searchtitle']; } ?>" class="product-new-textbox" name="searchtitle" value='' />
</form>
```

OR you can use get method as well

```
<form action="" >
    <select name="searchtitle" id="drp_dwn">
      <option value="one" >One</option>
      <option value="Two" >Two</option>
      <option value="Three" >Three</option>
    </select>     
    <input type="submit" onclick="showText()" class="button" value="Show">
    <input type="text" id="textArea" value="<?php if(isset(@$_GET['searchtitle'])){ echo $_GET['searchtitle']; } ?>" class="product-new-textbox" name="searchtitle" value='' />
</form>
```